# Revolution plot 3D of a y equation

Tags: plotting

I have the equations `|2y - 4|, {y, 0, 4}` and `2y - 4, {y, 4, 6}` and I want to revolution plot them as a piecewise function but along the x-axis. I applied the `ParametricPlot` to the absolute value function because I want the function to be horizontal and it worked, but only in the 2D plot. Do you have any idea of what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Functions look like this:

```
ParametricPlot[Piecewise[{{{2 y - 4, y}, 4 <= y <= 6}, {{Abs[2 y - 4], y}, 
0 <= y < 4}}], {y, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

Now we can combine to `RevolutionPlot3D`:

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{Abs[2 y - 4], y}, {y, 0, 4}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"], 
 RevolutionPlot3D[{2 y - 4, y}, {y, 4, 6}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"]]
```

[image]